# Failed Communication Between Already-Running MacVim Instance and Mutt

Tags: vim, mutt

I am using the mutt email client and am trying to use MacVim as my editor. I have set `editor = "mvim --remote"`. The `--remote` option to `mvim` opens a file in an existing instance of MacVim instead of opening a new window. While this successfully opens a file in my existing MacVim instance, there are two issues:

- mutt immediately displays the message "Aborted unmodified message.", despite the fact that a MacVim buffer was opened
- the headers do not appear at the top of the MacVim buffer (even though I have `set autoedit` in my mutt config).
- when I close the file with `:wq` mutt does not detect it-- it just continues showing "Aborted unmodified message."

These issues suggest that mutt is able to signal MacVim to open a new file, but is somehow unable to read/write from this file, detects this immediately, and considers the message aborted. I see the same issue if I use plain `mvim` or `mvim -f --remote`. But `mvim -f` works well-- my issue with it is that the startup time for MacVim is then annoyingly long due to all the plugins that get loaded. Can someone explain the mechanics of the communication between MacVim and Mutt, and whether there is a way to use the already open instance of MacVim as the editor?

Comment: Since your are already working in your terminal… why not simply `vim`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* exactly this works, but I was able to get the desired functionality by using

```
set editor = "mvim --remote-wait"
```

This properly opens up the message buffer in MacVim. When the buffer is deleted, mutt resumes with access to the newly created message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, mutt spawns the editor and waits for it to finish. After it has finished, it checks whether the initial file has been modified and if not, gives you the error message about an umodified message so it aborts.
In your case, vim just sends a remote edit command to another Vim instance and then exits, which makes mutt think, you are already finished with editing your message and because you haven't touched the message yet, it aborts.

Unfortunately, I do not have a solution for your problem. You would need a script, that spawns vim in the background and stays alive until you are finished with the file. But not sure, how it could detect that.

Comment: Hmm... are you sure this is correct? I'm not sure why my above solution works if Mutt is waiting for the editor to finish. What is the mechanism by which it checks whether it is finished?

Comment: When the process terminates?

Comment: I don't think it checks when the process terminates, because `mvim --remote-wait` opens the message in my already-running MacVim process, and mutt resumes when I delete the buffer (the MacVim process is still running).